# Example source code for SignerSignEx to sign an .exe file?

Tags: windows, cryptography, code-signing

I want to codesign an .exe file using an API rather than running signtool.exe.  The documentation for SignerSignEx is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387734(VS.85).aspx

It seems to be recommended as a modern replacement for the CapiCom library, based on this documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375732(VS.85).aspx#_crypto2_digital_signature_objects

Is there any sample code somewhere for how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a simple enough sample here in Alejandro Campos Magencio's [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/12/11/how-to-sign-exe-files-with-an-authenticode-certificate-part-2.aspx).
It begins with CAPICOM, but fear not, the second half is about `SignerSignEx`. It also ends with a troubleshooting tip.

I've always used signtool.exe myself. Are you having any issues with it?

G'luck

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  The main reason I don't want to use signtool.exe is that you can't legally redistribute it with open source code.

Comment: For a Java implementation, `ebourg/jsign` is a great tool.